# Data does not appear in linked tables (SubCategory and Products)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In the table "Categories" the data is displayed normally. But I can't get data in tables: "SubCategories" and "Products". The values in the columns are == null. Foreign keys between tables appear when viewed by the designer. Previously, there were no such problems, but suddenly a problem appeared with using asynchrony.

> 1. [Image1](https://ibb.co/Z674hfW) 2) [Image2](https://ibb.co/Pw2P1Qc)
>    Logger1: [Logger](http://ibb.co/3rpzswf) Logger2: [Logger](http://Logger)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        CreateIfDbNotExists(host);
        host.Run();
    }

    public static void CreateIfDbNotExists(IHost host)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                ApplicationDbContextSeed.SeedAsync(context, loggerFactory).Wait();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**EDIT :**
Entity models -

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SubCategory Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext -

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Category");
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<SubCategory>().ToTable("SubCategory");
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Product");
    }
}
```

Data seeding -

```
public static class ApplicationDbContextSeed
{
    public static async Task SeedAsync(ApplicationDbContext _context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            await SeedCategoriesAsync(_context);
            await SeedSubCategories(_context);
            await SeedProduct(_context);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ApplicationDbContext>();
            log.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    
    private static async Task SeedCategoriesAsync(ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        if (_context.Categories.Any()) return;
        var categories = new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category
            {
                Description = "Some category",
                CategoryName = "Electronics"
            },
            new Category
            {
                Description = "Some category",
                CategoryName = "Computers"
            },
            new Category
            {
                Description = "Some category",
                CategoryName = "Music"
            },
            new Category
            {
                Description = "Some category",
                CategoryName = "Software"
            },
            new Category
            {
                Description = "Some category",
                CategoryName = "Arts"
            },
            new Category
            {
                Description = "Some category",
                CategoryName = "Games"
            },
        };
        _context.Categories.AddRange(categories);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private static async Task SeedSubCategories(ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        if (_context.SubCategories.Any()) return;
        var subCategories = new List<SubCategory>
        {
            new SubCategory
            {
                CategoryID =  _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                SubCategoryName = "Camera",
                Description = "Some"
            },
            new SubCategory
            {
                CategoryID =  _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                SubCategoryName = "Phones",
                Description = "Some"
            },
            new SubCategory
            {
                CategoryID =  _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                SubCategoryName = "Headphones",
                Description = "Some"
            },
            new SubCategory
            {
                CategoryID =  _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == "Electronics").CategoryID,
                SubCategoryName = "Video Game Consoles && Accessories",
                Description = "Some"
            },
        };
        _context.SubCategories.AddRange(subCategories);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private static async Task SeedProduct(ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        if (_context.Products.Any()) return;
        var products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "iPhone 12 Pro Max",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Phones").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1695.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Phones").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "Xiaomi 9 Pro",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Phones").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "Canon PowerShot SX540 Digital Camera",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Camera").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "Panasonic LUMIX FZ300",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Camera").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "Panasonic LUMIX FZ300",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Camera").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "4K Digital Camera 48MP Camera",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Camera").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "TOZO T10 Bluetooth 5.0", 
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Headphones").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "TOZO T6 True Wireless",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Headphones").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "Razer Kraken Tournament Edition",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Headphones").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "Sony PlayStation 4 Pro (1TB) Console with Red Dead Redemption 2 Bundle",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Video Game Consoles && Accessories").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
            new Product
            {
                ProductName = "PlayStation 4 Console - 1TB Slim Edition",
                SubCategoryID = _context.SubCategories.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubCategoryName == "Video Game Consoles && Accessories").SubCategoryID,
                UnitPrice = 1395.66,
                ImagePath = "iphone12.webp",
                Description = "Some phone"
            },
        };

        _context.Products.AddRange(products);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)] 
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public int? SubCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to change ```ApplicationDbContextSeed.SeedAsync(context, loggerFactory).Wait();``` for ```await ApplicationDbContextSeed.SeedAsync(context, loggerFactory)```

Comment: Tried it first by applying "await". Didn't help =((

Comment: And why don't you just add the whole entities as ```new Category()
  {
   Name = "some category"
   SubCategories = new List<SubCategories>()
   {
    new SubCategory()
    {
     Name = "somename",
     Products = new List<Product>()
     {
      new Product(){}
     }
    }
   }
  }```

Comment: Well, format went wrong hope you catch the idea 

Comment: Did you see any exception message logged?

Comment: I saw: "An error occured while updating entries". But I don't know hot to solve this problem. I found it, maybe it works. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214860/entity-framework-an-error-occurred-while-updating-the-entries-see-the-inner)

Comment: Photo: https://ibb.co/3rpzswf 
Photo2: https://ibb.co/bLdk1K9

Comment: It's so difficult to understand what's the problem...

Comment: Could you show your Category and SubCategory class please?  And the db context for them.

Comment: updated at number 2

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry but  could you add a Product class too, pls.

Comment: Thanks for update, but you forgot to add  Product class.

Comment: You might want to look into EF Migrations.

Comment: Agree with Sergey, the issue is related to the string length, By using your code, if you check the set a break point in the SeedAsync method catch statement. You will find an exception when seed data for the SubCategory: [`String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAwIx.png) After changing the string length from `[StringLength(30)]` to `[StringLength(300)]`, the data inserted successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that SubCategoryName is too short for "Video Game Consoles && Accessories". This gives an exception. Now it is varchar(30). Should be varchar(50) at least. All tables were seeded succesfully after I made some subcategory name and product name values shorter.

I recommend you to fix the SubCategory and Product  classes by replacing [StringLength(30)] by [StringLength(96)] or even larger.

```
....
    [StringLength(96)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

  [StringLength(96)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
.....
```